# Display department and number of computers made by Dell allocated in that department

Tags: sql

How to do this one,I am stuck.
Schema is as follows
Computer (Compid, Make, Model, Myear)
Employee (Id, Ename, Doj, Salary, Bonus, Dept, Designation, Manager, Compid).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
    select  a.dept
         ,  count(*)    as [count]
      from  employee a 
      join  computer b
        on  a.compid = b.compid
     where  b.make = 'Dell'
  group by  a.dept
         ,  b.make
```